# Accessing a particular <td> for a given <tr> and changing the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Hi thanx for the help for my previous question... It helped me lot...
But now I'm facing another issue,
I'm able to refresh my "Table" for every 5 seconds(here is my code for that)

```
function GetStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Site/StatusReport/",
        type: "GET",
        data: '',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            // var type = $.parseJSON(result);
            var row = "";

            $(result).each(function () {
                // row += "<tr><td>" + this.SiteId + "</td></tr></br>";
                // row += "<tr><td>" + this.SiteName + "</td></tr>";
                // row += "<tr><td>" + this.SiteStatus + "</td></tr>";  
                changeStatus(this.SiteId, this.SiteName, this.SiteStatus);
            });
            // $("#sometable").html(row);
        }
    });
}
```

and the json data is rendered into a table using the following code

```
<table id="sometable" > 
    <tr> 
        <th></th>
        <th>SiteName</th> 
        <th>SiteStatus</th> 
        <th></th> 
    </tr> 

    <%foreach (var item in (List<MvcList.Models.CenterStatus>)ViewData["table"])
      { %>
        <tr id ="<%= item.SiteId%>"> 
            <td>
               <img  src='../../Content/<%= item.SiteName%>.png'/>
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <%= item.SiteName%>
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <%= item.SiteStatus %>
            </td>          
        </tr> 
    <%} %>
</table>
```

But now I need to change the color of a particular SiteStatus depending upon its value (for example say if the site status is "Low Tickets" in the database i want to change the color of that particualar sitestatus ...
I have used this for that

```
function changeStatus(data1, data2, data3) {
    if (data3 = "Low Tickets") {
        // $("#sometable[id='" + data1 + "']tr td:nth-child(2)").addClass("LowTicket");
        // $("#sometable tr:nth-child(3)").addClass("LowTicket");
        // $("#sometable tr:nth-child(4)>td:nth-child(3)").addClass("LowTicket");
        $('table #sometable tr:nth-child(' + data1 + ')>td:nth-child(3)').addClass("LowTicket");
    } 
}
```

But the code is not working. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Are you considering that the :nth-child() pseudo-selector is only supported in ie 9 and up?

Comment: @Faust - That looks like jQuery to me.  With jQuery, Sizzle takes care of old browsers that don't support CSS3.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. No problem with :nth-child() as a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be

```
function changeStatus(data1, data2, data3) {
  if (data3 = "Low Tickets") {
    $('#sometable tr#' + data1 + '>td:nth-child(3)').addClass("LowTicket");
  } 
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLvRM/)

**Edit**

If you want to highlight all LowLevel lines you could simply use

```
$("tr td:contains('LowTicket')").parent().addClass("LowTicket");
```

see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WLvRM/)

Comment: julien:- it works but ts addingclass(LowTicket) to my entire sitestatus column but not just for "Low ticket" ...What you gave me i achieved that before bt i need to change the html of that particular sitestatus ....

Comment: It Should not maybe you `data1` value is incorrect, see if my edit is more helpful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do but i think you want to change the row that the third column to "LowTicket" class name;

if it is,

You can call once of javascript when data loaded, by replace

```
$(result).each(function () {
            //                        row += "<tr><td>" + this.SiteId + "</td></tr></br>";
            //                        row += "<tr><td>" + this.SiteName + "</td></tr>";
            // row += "<tr><td>" + this.SiteStatus + "</td></tr>";  
            changeStatus(this.SiteId, this.SiteName, this.SiteStatus);

        });
```

to

```
$('#sometable tr>td:nth-child(3)').each(function(){
    if ($(this).html() == "Low Tickets"){
        $(this).parent().addClass("LowTicket"); //For change class of parent rows
        // Or
        // $(this).addClass("LowTicket"); //For change class only status column
    }
});
```

Hope this help you.